# Does UTF-8 have a UCS synonym like how UTF-16 is UCS-2 and UTF-32 is UCS-4?

Tags: unicode

while browsing the unicode documentation I sometimes see the term UTF-16 interchangeably used with UCS-2 and the same thing with UTF-32 and UCS-4. I was wondering if UTF-8 also has a cool nickname like UCS-1 or something...

Comment: Who is it a nickname ?  it’s same length

Comment: FWIW, UTF-16 *isn't* UCS-2. UCS-2 only covered the BMP; UTF-16 was the extension (by adding surrogate pairs) to cover the higher planes as well, extending the space from 16 bits to 21.

Comment: The practical, programmatic difference between UCS-2 and UTF-16 is that in UCS-2 every code unit is a codepoint so that string length "works". That was the basis for many programming languages (Java, JavaScript, .NET, etc) Programs that use UTF-16 string length to determine the number of codepoints are just wrong (or, if you prefer, correct for a limited range of data).

Comment: @TomBlodget I'd consider the fact that UTF-16 can handle valid data produced in 1996 or later while UCS-2 can't promise to be able to do so a bigger practical, programmatic difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Nor are they quite the same.

UCS-2 is an obsolete encoding of ISO 10646 (a standard that these days is pretty much Unicode but without some of its rules about how characters should be treated) and Unicode Version 1 in 2 octets (8-bit bytes) per character. Prior to 1996 that allowed it to encode all of the Universal Character Set (hence *UCS*), but it doesn't work for all of Unicode Version 2 or later (we're currently on Version 10).

UTF-16 uses 2-octet groups to encode either characters or pairs of surrogates (so 4 octets in total) to encode U+10000 and higher. It is backwards compatible with UCS-2, so anything that can handle UTF-16 will understand UCS-2 as being valid UTF-16, but old software expecting UCS-2 will see the surrogates as being normal characters (which it won't understand, since the relevant code points weren't assigned to anything in Unicode Version 1).

UCS-4 was originally defined by ISO 10646 as a 32-bit encoding using 4 octets per character, and theoretically able to support code points up to U+7FFFFFFF (the highest bit was never going to be set to 1 to avoid confusion where support for unsigned 32-bit values wasn't great). ISO has since stated that ISO 10646 will never assign a code point differently to Unicode and hence never above U+10FFFF.

UTF-32 was defined by the Unicode Consortium much the same way as UCS-4 was, except that it had the stated limit of U+10FFFF from its beginning. So while the two once differed in theoretical (but unused) limits, they are now the same. But because they were once different, it's not quite true to say that they are different names for the same things. (They're more like identical twins than someone with two names).

UTF-8 uses 1, 2, 3 or 4 octets per character, depending on the code point. It was developed at the time when ISO 10646 and Unicode differed on the maximum possible code point and intended to be usable with either, while remaining backwards compatible with 8-bit encodings of ASCII/ISO 646. Therefore it originally could also have 5 or 6 octets to support the U+110000 to U+7FFFFFFF range that ISO 10646 supported but Unicode didn't. Since U+10FFFF is now the maximum for both, those 5 and 6 octet combinations are no longer allowed by it.

Before UTF-8 was UTF-8, it was X/Open's FSS-UTF ("File System Safe UCS Transformation Format"), so that's sort of "a cool nickname", if you consider FSS-UTF "cool".

Answer (score 0):

It may also be worth noting that "UTF-16" and "UTF-32" may denote either *encoding forms* (ways of representing text *inside* an application) or *encoding schemes* (ways of transmitting text *between* applications or computers). In the former case, byte order is unspecified (dictated by the hardware or compiler), while in the latter byte order does matter. The *encoding schemes* mandate a leading file signature to specify the byte order, while the *encoding forms* forbid such a byte order mark (any such byte sequence would have to be considered part of the "payload").

Similar considerations apply to "UTF-8", even though byte order does not matter there; the difference in this case is that the *encoding scheme* also allows for (but does not mandate) a leading signature (which "happens" to match the UTF-8 encoding for the code point that corresponds to the UTF-16 and UTF-32 byte order signatures). The *encoding form* explicitly forbids such a signature, and any such sequence would have to be considered part of the "payload".

The UTF-16 and UTF-32 *encoding schemes* are complemented by UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE and UTF-32BE, which are encoding schemes that explicitly forbid a leading byte order mark and instead demand that byte order be negotiated by other means.